# How can you combine these 2 functions into 1?

Tags: jquery, function

I have two divs which I need to show the opposite upon click.

You can see the site here as to what I mean: http://thomasbritton.co.uk/projects/akw/

Basically when you click 1 option it shows more details about it.

Have currently got it working with the following jQuery:

```
$('.consumer').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).next().hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});

$('.trade').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).prev().hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});
```

But I'm sure there must be a way of combing these 2 functions into 1, I just can't figure out how.

Anyone able to help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `.trade` panel the `next()` element of `.consumer' and vice versa? That is, do you only want one of those panels to be shown at any given time?

Comment: The only difference is the `.prev`/`.next`.  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Yes .trade is the next() element and yes only 1 can be shown at a time

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for all your help. They all work but have decided to go for the reply from Rocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?  Uses `.siblings` instead of `.next`/`.prev` to get the element(s).

```
$('.consumer,.trade').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).siblings('.consumer,.trade').hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.consumer, .trade').live('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('expanded');
  if ($(this).hasClass('consumer'))
    $(this).next().hide();
  else
    $(this).prev().hide();
  $('.expanded h2').hide();
  $('.striped').hide();
  $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.consumer,.trade').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    if ($(this).is(".consumer"))
     $(this).prev().hide();
    if ($(this).is(".trade"))
     $(this).next().hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: `.consumer` had `$(this).next().hide();` whereas `.trade` had `$(this).prev().hide();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.consumer, .trade').live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $this[$this.is('.consumer') ? "next" : "prev"]().hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.consumer, .trade').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $('.options:not(.expanded)').hide();
    $('.expanded h2').hide();
    $('.striped').hide();
    $('.expanded_content', $(this)).fadeIn();
});
```